# Why is Python adding key and function to OrderedDict?

Tags: python, lambda, ordereddictionary

Here is part of my program:

```
print(str(alphabet) + " ")
alphabet = OrderedDict(alphabet, key=lambda x: x[0])
print(str(alphabet) + " ")
```

Here's the output to the terminal of that part:

```
{' ': (57301, 0.16656008557492746), 'a': (23596, 0.06858783929121637), 'c': (8761, 0.025466098492555794), 'b': (5129, 0.014908756896281095), 'e': (32343, 0.0940132431851081), 'd': (9401, 0.027326423002912572), 'g': (6125, 0.01780388691552383), 'f': (5582, 0.016225517838768), 'i': (24438, 0.0710353287251545), 'h': (10526, 0.03059652468127409), 'k': (1985, 0.005769912739153436), 'j': (622, 0.001808002883502991), 'm': (9517, 0.027663606820414736), 'l': (12504, 0.0363460901210955), 'o': (20552, 0.05973967083883195), 'n': (19586, 0.05693174353101219), 'q': (840, 0.0024416759198432674), 'p': (8986, 0.0261201188282281), 's': (20204, 0.05872811938632545), 'r': (18284, 0.053147145855255123), 'u': (7068, 0.020544958811252637), 't': (26396, 0.07672675902402726), 'w': (3767, 0.010949753797678083), 'v': (3136, 0.0091155901007482), 'y': (3600, 0.010464325370756861), 'x': (3004, 0.008731898170487114), 'z': (773, 0.0022469231976652926)} 
OrderedDict([(' ', (57301, 0.16656008557492746)), ('a', (23596, 0.06858783929121637)), ('c', (8761, 0.025466098492555794)), ('b', (5129, 0.014908756896281095)), ('e', (32343, 0.0940132431851081)), ('d', (9401, 0.027326423002912572)), ('g', (6125, 0.01780388691552383)), ('f', (5582, 0.016225517838768)), ('i', (24438, 0.0710353287251545)), ('h', (10526, 0.03059652468127409)), ('k', (1985, 0.005769912739153436)), ('j', (622, 0.001808002883502991)), ('m', (9517, 0.027663606820414736)), ('l', (12504, 0.0363460901210955)), ('o', (20552, 0.05973967083883195)), ('n', (19586, 0.05693174353101219)), ('q', (840, 0.0024416759198432674)), ('p', (8986, 0.0261201188282281)), ('s', (20204, 0.05872811938632545)), ('r', (18284, 0.053147145855255123)), ('u', (7068, 0.020544958811252637)), ('t', (26396, 0.07672675902402726)), ('w', (3767, 0.010949753797678083)), ('v', (3136, 0.0091155901007482)), ('y', (3600, 0.010464325370756861)), ('x', (3004, 0.008731898170487114)), ('z', (773, 0.0022469231976652926)), ('key', <function <lambda> at 0x1619f30>)])
```

In case you are wondering this is counting all the letters in a file. The values in the tuples are count and probability of this letter occurring.

Why does it add '('key',  at 0x1619f30>)'?

Comment: What are you expecting the `key` argument to do?  OrderedDict doesn't accept any special `key` argument, so it's just added to the dict as an ordinary key.

Comment: @ BrenBarn: You're right about me not fulling understanding what it was supposed to do. I thought that it took an argument in the 'constructor', if that's the right term in Python, which you wanted it to be ordered by. The bit I was missing was sorted(alphabet) so that line should have been: alphabet = OrderedDict(sorted(alphabet.items()), key=lambda x: x[0])

Comment: @myself: Actually that's: alphabet = OrderedDict(sorted(alphabet.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])). Put it on the right side of the bracket!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to ensure your dictionary has the keys in alphabetical order? If so, you'll need to insert them one at a time into the OrderedDict after first sorting them. The following code will do that.

```
# Extract keys from dictionary into list and sort them
keys = list(alphabet).sort()

# Now insert them into the new ordered dictionary.
d = OrderedDict() 
for k in keys:
    d[k] = alphabet[k]
```

If you have Python 2.7+ you can use a dictionary comprehension and do the whole thing in one fell swoop:

```
d = {k: alphabet[k] for k in list(alphabet).sort()}
```

Answer (score 1):

OrderedDict doesn't accept any special `key` argument, so that argument just added to the dict as an ordinary key.

However, from the looks of your code, I'm guessing you have a more fundamental misunderstanding about OrderedDict.  Did you read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects)?

> Ordered dictionaries are just like regular dictionaries but they remember the **order that items were inserted**.

Note what I emphasized.  The "Ordered" in OrderedDict doesn't meant "sorted".  The items are not compared to each other in any way.  It only remembers what order they were added.